# Error: could not decode result data (value="0x", info={ "method": "retrive", "signature": "retrive()" }, code=BAD_DATA, version=6.11.1)

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, ethers.js, testnets, sepolia

```
const fs = require("fs-extra")
const ethers = require("ethers")
const { JsonRpcProvider } = require("ethers")
require("dotenv").config()

async function main() {
  let provider = new JsonRpcProvider(process.env.RPC_URL)
  let wallet = new ethers.Wallet(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY, provider)
  const abi = fs.readFileSync("./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.abi", "utf-8")
  const binary = fs.readFileSync(
    "./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.bin",
    "utf-8"
  )
  contractFactory = new ethers.ContractFactory(abi, binary, wallet)
  console.log(process.env.RPC_URL)
  console.log(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY, provider)
  console.log("Deploying please wait...")
  const contract = await contractFactory.deploy()
  console.log(contract)
  const signer = wallet.connect(provider)
  const nonce = await signer.getNonce()


  const currentFavoriteNumber = await contract.retrive()
  console.log(await contract.retrive())
  console.log(`Current Favorite Number: ${currentFavoriteNumber.toString()}`)
  const transactionResponse = await contract.store("12", { nonce: nonce })
  const transactionReceipt = await transactionResponse.wait(1)
  const updatedFavoriteNumber = await contract.retrive()
  console.log(`Updated Favorite Number ${updatedFavoriteNumber}`)
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error)
    process.exit(1)
  })
```

Hi, on this code i am running into an error: when I am using Alchemy RPC_URL then it gives this error otherwise when I am using ganache there is nothing; Every thing is correct then

Error: could not decode result data (value="0x", info={ "method": "retrive", "signature": "retrive()" }, code=BAD_DATA, version=6.11.1)
below is my RPC_URL but if I am using ganache then there is not any error; all the things are correct then

RPC_URL=https://eth-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/4yaYwZaOaEmkkyauFaNX6tVY2nkA51aQ
can someone help me?

Comment: It seems a function is failing and revert, so ethers is getting the expected return value.

Comment: Can you add the content of **SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.abi** & **SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.bin** in your question?